# What is the technical reason that GraphQL allows to define array with nullable entries?

Tags: graphql

In GraphQL you can define an array where any/every member can be null, i.e. `[Vote]` or `[Vote]!`. This necessitates that we always use an inner exclamation mark (`[Vote!]!`).

```
declaration accepts: | null | []   | [null] | [{foo: 'BAR'}]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Vote!]!             | no   | yes  | no     | yes
[Vote]!              | no   | yes  | yes    | yes
[Vote!]              | yes  | yes  | no     | yes
[Vote]               | yes  | yes  | yes    | yes
```

I cannot think of a valid use case for `[Vote]!`.

What design would ever have such a requirement? Is this for graceful error handling?

Answer (score 1):

It's desirable to have the individual item in the list be nullable because of [the way GraphQL handles errors and non-nullability](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Errors-and-Non-Nullability). Specifically with regard to lists:

> If a List type wraps a Non-Null type, and one of the elements of that list resolves to null, then the entire list must resolve to null. If the List type is also wrapped in a Non-Null, the field error continues to propagate upwards.

So we can imagine a scenario where an error occurs while resolving some field on an individual `Vote` item. The field the error occurs on is non-nullable, so the item itself is made null. If the parent field's type is `[Vote]` or `[Vote]!`, then the buck stops there and a null is returned as part of the list (with an error in the `errors` array to explain what went wrong). However, if we have `[Vote!]`, then the entire list will be made null. If we have `[Vote!]!` then the list can't be null and the error will continue bubbling up until it hits a nullable field.

In this way, if you make extensive use of non-nulls, a single error deep down the tree can cause the entire `data` value in the response to be null. While this may be fine in some cases, it's often better to be able to at least render a partial result instead of nothing at all. This is also why it's arguably good practice to avoid non-nulls in general except in cases where the object wouldn't be usable without a particular field (like an `id` field).

Outside of error handling, are there scenarios where returning a list containing nulls makes sense? An example might be an operation that looks up a list of objects based on a provided array of IDs. In this case, it may be desirable for the result array to match the length (and order) of the ID array, so a null could be used to indicate no matching object was found.

Comment: I never dealt with a scenario where it would be desirable to return partial response in case of an error. I guess I am taught that if there is an error, then it should fail loud. This way errors do not linger ignored.

Comment: As for the use case where input order dictates result older, that sounds (for a network based API) a horrible design. Each result should have an envelope that pairs request parameters with the result. I am sure it exists in the wild, though.

Comment: Allowing for partial responses does not mean you don't do error handling. If a portion of the graph returns null due to an error and the error is recoverable, then you can still retry the request but you at least have something to render for the user and reduce TTI. Better still, you can potentially request only the part of your graph that's still missing instead of retrying the whole original request.

Comment: And if the error is not recoverable, is it the best experience for the end user to just render nothing or some generic error message? To put it in perspective, imagine a single query that fetched all the data necessary to render this page. Would you really want to "fail loud" just because there was an issue resolving the salary field on a job listing to the right?

Comment: For one, "a single query that fetched all the data necessary to render this page" is not a thing outside of a handful of frameworks (such as Relay). Even then, whether I would expect the entire page to fail or not would depend on the product. Entirely from development perspective, the stricter the contract, the easier it is to develop the product. Allowing partial results in case of an error drastically complicates all the scenarios that need to be handled.

Comment: I'm just trying to provide some context around why GraphQL does what it does, for better or for worse. I didn't mean to imply that's the only or necessarily best way of doing error handling, but I realize that's how it sounded :) Obviously everything "depends on the product". Historically speaking, though, Facebook was the product and Relay was the framework. So you have to view "why was GraphQL designed this way", in that context.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for providing some context.